# Are there browsers that don't support writing to window?

Tags: javascript

I see that unless otherwise specified `window.[[Writeable]]` [should be true](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1) for all javascript environments. And I don't seem to find any [information](http://caniuse.com/) to the contrary.

Is there any compatibility concern with storing some javascript state in `window.foo` (for example)?

Comment: how far back do you want to go? Anyway no, other than name conflicts

Comment: All javascript environments, including non-browser environments?

Comment: Browser only. I think `IE8` timeframe is our limit

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn’t. `window` is the global object in every browser.

(If there ever was a browser that didn’t treat the global object as writeable, you should treat it as not supporting JavaScript and provide fallbacks accordingly.)